# Firewall rules does not apply to pfsense hosted machine

Tags: freebsd, ping, pfsense, icmp

I am using pfsense as my home firewall and configured multi-wan setup.

In addition, I have installed package 'Telegraf ' package for exporting my pfsense stats into InfluxDB, also in 'Telegraf' configuration I have enabled 'Ping Monitor' for 4 different hosts.

[image: Grafana stats]

Since, all ping packets go through the default gateway and I wanted to create separate rule for each ping hosts to forward them manually.

*My goal is to track latency of each gateway/wan so I can complain to my ISP with solid facts lol. Also, I need to track that pings before I play online competitive games, to make sure it does not ruin my game*

[image: Firewall rules]

But these firewall rules does not work. When I start download from my default (UzonlineGW) gateway, in my Grafana stats I can see that ping to all hosts increase equally.

Also when I traceroute to all 4 hosts from pfsense shell, pfsense uses my default gateway (UzonlineGW).

My first thought was, it might be because pfsense is not in LAN, but I am not sure about that.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have asked same question on netgate forum.

Solution is here: https://forum.netgate.com/topic/159396/firewall-rules-does-not-apply-to-pfsense-hosted-machine